# How to run vimscript function on visually selected lines of text?

Tags: vimscript, filetype-xml

I'm editing DocBook XML files and sometimes I need to format the using an external `xmlformat` command. it is easy to run do this on the whole buffer of text, but how can i achieve the same only for a visually selected lines of text?

EDIT1: simply running `!xmlformat` on selected lines works. the problem is that i need to do more things to the lines, such as get the number of indent of the first line, do the formatting, then shift the block to the indent size so that it aligns with the rest of the text.. It's summarized in https://github.com/tbazant/vim-daps/issues/38 BTW

EDIT2: the function in my plugin should be defined the way that it can handle either no input (run xmlformat on the whole file/buffer) or range of selected lines

Comment: Does simply typing `!xmlformat` work? If not, maybe you could edit the question to explain why. `:help v_!`

Comment: To more precisely I think Rich means using `:'<,'>!xmlformat` after a visual selection: `'<` and `'>` are marks which refer to the last visually selected text.

Comment: Question header is quite different to the body I would say. There is a way to run a vimscript function on visually selected lines but here it is about filtering of visual selection using external tool.

Comment: @statox: Yes, but you don't need to type the colon or the range, simply pressing `!` directly from the visual selection will add both automatocally. (I know you know this already.)

Comment: Right @Rich I was just giving more details as I think it can be confusing for someone who doesn't know that :) But your point about editing the question if that doesn't work is still completely relevant

Comment: @statox: i've updated the problem description, would be nice if you can have a look

Comment: Rather than counting the white-spaces and all of that I have two suggestions: After using `!xmlformat` maybe you can use `'<='>` to align the text you previously formatted OR maybe if you use something like `'<-1,'>+1!xmlformat` the external program takes into consideration the surrounding lines and adapt the indentation? Otherwise if you want more details on how to accept a range in a function have a look at [`:h function-range-example`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#function-range-example) (I'm pretty sure we have other questions about range functions too)

Comment: @statox how do i apply `=` indentation on `'<-1,'>+1` ? Typing `'<-1,'>+1=` on selected lines does not work